# How can i style custom text fields on cart page?

Tags: woocommerce

Hope someone can help me.
i have a custom text field at my cart page with the ID _shipping_field - how can i style this text if i eg. want the text to be green and bold writing.

```
function product_create_field() {
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => '_shipping_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Skriv kort beskrivelse her',
            'label' => __('kort beskrivelse', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'product_create_field', 10, 0 );


function woo_add_custom_general_fields_supplier_save( $product ) {
    if( isset($_POST['_shipping_field']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_shipping_field', esc_html( $_POST['_shipping_field'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_supplier_save', 10, 1 );


function delivery_time_in_cart_display( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $shipping_field = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_shipping_field');
    
    
    if ( ! empty( $shipping_field ) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $shipping_field,          
                                
        );
    }
    
    return $item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'delivery_time_in_cart_display', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom style in admin area like this -

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');

function my_custom_css() {
  echo '<style>
     #_shipping_field {
       color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
     }
  </style>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer - your code works perfeckt as you have descripet. - but what i meant was how do i make the text on the cart page, and check out page, bold, and green?